# what is the critics badge? i did not down vote any.

Tags: support, down-votes

Hi,
 I got the Critic badge in Stack Overflow. It said it is for down voting. i did not down vote any answers. i accidentally voted and again revoked. How to fine which post i have down voted if i had accidentally done that.? Where should i ask such quesitons as this is for superuser i know this is an inappropriate question here. So please move to the specific site and i will follow it.

Besides if this question needs to be deleted then its ok but i want to know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this question should have been asked on Meta.StackOverflow.com, but don't worry, it can stay here.

If you (accidently) downvoted a post, you won't be able to revert it unless the post is edited. But really, it's not the end of the world, though you could leave a comment to apologize.

However, since we don't have access to your voting pattern, we can't tell you were you did it. So my advice: enjoy the rest of the day and to up your karma: upvote every good question or answer you see!

Answer (score 4):

You can undo a vote, but after a minute or so you can't any more.

Maybe you downvoted by accident and reverted, and you got a badge for that.

I have the Critics badge in SuperUser Meta for this reason, I got it by accident, but my downvote withdrawal was done.

Comment: I have the Critic badge in SO and SU for the same reason; I accidentally hit the down vote button and then immediately reverted it. It looks as though you get the badge the moment you hit the down vote button; the system can't tell if you just hit it by accident.